# Prevent extraction of Links from Flutter release apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, decompiler

I came across with many websites which decompile APK. For Example this website [Java Decompiler](https://www.decompiler.com/) I was able to decompile the APK and get all the links which were used in the project. My Question is there any way we prevent some files/folder from being decompiled to protect the static links/Secret keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `progaurd` in your `build.gradle` to protect the static links/Secret keys.

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
         
            release{
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                        'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                        'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: proguard: a) doesn't obfuscate strings,b) doesn't touch  dart compiled binaries ... and question was about flutter